# Where do these game pieces belong?

Tags: identify-this-game

On BoardGameGeek someone posted a picture of Mongols, Japanese, and Chinese (along with Frederick?) game pieces. It's posted under the game called Khan: The Rise of the Mongols, but that game uses different pieces. Can somebody identify the pieces in this picture? Many thanks. Picture below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Link to full picture [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/578692/khan-rise-mongols) (the full pic was too big to post so I posted them separately in screenshots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description on that image says "Optional counters (see files)", and if you go to the Files section of the game on BGG there are a number of PDF files that call themselves "Optional countersheet for Khan" that look just like that image.

At a guess, they're designed to replace the counters that come with the game to either be more readable, or look nicer, or something.